# Could an amputated Emperor still shoot lightning?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, darth-sidious

If the Emperor's hands were amputated, would he still be able to shoot lightning?  What about if his arms were completely removed?

**Note:** I am looking for a canon-based answer.

Comment: Inspired by the *Return of the Jedi* Movie Event in chat.

Comment: Well, with all the stock cybernetics, he'd just have to reboot after...

Comment: Can an amputated Emperor use force-lighting to close an SE duplicate?

Comment: Also related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/85882/31936. The Emperor could summon lightning from the sky rather than from his body.

Comment: @Null Neither this question nor the one you claim it to be a duplicate of were sufficiently answered with canon evidence. Wouldn't it be best to get an answer before declaring a dupe?

Comment: @Axelrod I think [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/110322/31936), which uses canon-based reasoning, suffices for this question. We haven't seen Force Lightning projected from anywhere but one's hands in canon, so we're left with educated guesses or Legends examples. If you or the asker want to VTRO, feel free.

Comment: @Axelrod : Thanks. I've voted to re-open.

Comment: @Null : I've VTRO'ed.

Comment: Could a Boba Fett with no lips still hum the Emperor's March? What kind of a crazy question is this?

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens Anakin's specialty in the movies is cutting off hands. When he tried to stop the Emperor, he body checked and picked him up, rather than simply cutting off his hands. The question, then, is if a handless Emperor could have continued using his lightning.

Comment: @Praxis I've also VTROed, but it looks like not enough others agree with us. Is my answer good enough to get the tick in the absence of others, or should I go and look for more evidence? :-)

Comment: @randal'thor: Didn't see this comment until now (likely because of mobile).  Thanks!  I'm looking for a canon answer (by the current definition of Star Wars canon).  When I'm okay with a Legends answer, I tag the question as such.  Let me know what you can dig up. :-)

Comment: Related:  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112496/can-darth-vader-use-force-lightning

Answer (score 4):

### Probably, yes.

As seen in [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34342/is-force-lightning-from-the-feet-plausible), channelling<sup>1</sup> Force lightning isn't dependent on having hands. @Richard even found a picture (from [Star Wars: Legacy #005](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Legacy)) of a Force user channelling Force lightning from their *entire body*:

[image]

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Yes, I'm using Wheel of Time terminology to answer a Star Wars question. So sue me.</sub>

Comment: Channelling is widely used in lots of works, not just your precious WoT!

Comment: For the record, this picture also implies that force-lightning can come from a wide variety of unpleasant places.

Comment: What's the picture from?

Comment: [Star Wars: Legacy](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/110323/20774)

Comment: @DaveJohnson See comment from Richard ^

Comment: "Channeling" is far from specific to Wheel of Time. That's like saying "Force = Mass x Acceleration" is a Star Wars reference.